# How can I click the submit button in this HTML code (has no name or ID) with MS Access VBA

Tags: html, vba, ms-access

The button on this HTML page doesn't have a name or ID so I am unable to click it.  I've scanned the previous questions but none are like this HTML that I can see.  I've not included the whole page but this is the section with the button in it that i need to click.

I'm using VBA from MS Access 2010 to maniupulate IE v8.  I'm still learning so apologies if it's easy (hope it is).  as you can see the SUBMIT input type has no name or ID.  thanks.

```
</div>
<div id="container">
<div class="group">
    <div id="content">
    <div class="banner">
<h2>Welcome</h2>
```

```
<div id="search-box">
    <form method="get">
        <label for="criteria">Search</label>
        <input type="text" id="search" name="search" value="" maxlength="255" />
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Search" />
    <p class="hint">Search by Order No. Service ID or Your reference ID</p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
Dim htmlButton
Set htmlButton = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementByID("search-box").GetElementsByTagname("Input")(1)

'' Test to see if we got the right element. (Comment out or remove this line later)
MsgBox htmlButton.Value

'' Click that button
htmlButton.Click
```

Comment: + 1 Neat :) You might want to add the `.Click` method? :)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: Done! :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use something like this:

```
Set tags = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagname("Input")

For Each tagx In tags
    If tagx.value = "Search" Then
        tagx.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Where wb is the WebBrowser control.

Comment: +1 Good trick. But you unnecessarily continue the loop even after you have found the correct control. Just put an `Exit For` before the `End If`.

Comment: thanks guys that did the trick - so easy in the end!  appreciate your help thanks again so much.