# Click button on webpage that doesn't have id tag

Tags: vbscript

I'm working on a vbscript and need some assistance with clicking a button on a website. How would I click a button on a website with no id? Here is what's available:

```
<INPUT class=Button type=submit value="Log In">
```

Comment: maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185709) can help you

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
For Each btn In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If btn.type = "submit" Then btn.Click()
Next
```